# Why compiler is getting angry with isomorphic types?

Tags: haskell, monads

```
Expected type: ErrorT String IO Integer
Actual type: IO (Either String Integer)
```

I have no idea, where I am wrong. After all, these types are isomorphic.
Of course, when I replace my signature of function from

```
ErrorT String IO Integer
```

to

```
IO (Either String Integer)
```

compiler is happy, but I am not happy because I am confused.

Comment: The complier checks for type equality, not isomorphism. Otherwise `newtype`s would be completely useless. Also, I would not want `case True of Left () -> 1 ; Right () -> 2` to type check.

Comment: compiler and his wife were driving to work today when a cop pulled them over. "Do you know why I pulled you over" the cop asks. "No officer" compiler replies. "You were driving without a seatbelt." "You must be mistaken officer, I had it on, see!" They go back and forth about whether the seat belt was on for a few minutes. The cop then leans down and says to the woman "Was compiler driving without his seat belt?" The woman replies "Officer, after forty years of marriage to compiler, I have learned one thing. Never argue with him when he's drunk!"
Compiler got a ticket. This is why he is angry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it's a bit tricky to answer because there is no real question but the Compiler is not happy because the types might be *isomorphic* but they are not synonymous - there is a `ErrorT` in the way:

```
newtype ErrorT e m a = ErrorT m (Either e a)
                       ^^^^^^
```

[see here](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl-2.2.1/docs/Control-Monad-Error.html#v:ErrorT)

you already had this in another one of your questions - it was the difference between something like

```
return (Left "Hello") :: IO (Either String Integer)
```

and

```
ErrorT (return (Left "Hello")) :: ErrorT String IO Integer
```

Comment: Yes, I asked about it, but I still don't understand. Nevertheless I make a small step of progress.  Is it possible to convert from `IO (Either String Bool)` to `ErrorT String IO Bool` ? It seems to me that it is sufficien to add (on the  begin) ErrorT

Comment: yes exactly! - that's what your last question was all about if I remember correctly - you indeed only need to wrap it with `ErrorT`